# libgit2sharp equivalent of git diff <SHA1> <filename>

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I'm looking for a way to get all changes of a file from a specific commit to the current HEAD. With the git utility I just call `git diff <sha1 of commit> <filename>`. Is this possible with libgit2sharp? By far I just achieved that libgit2sharp returned changes of all files that changed between commit and HEAD.

thanks in advance

Edit:
What I tried so far: 
Getting a commit at a given date in which a file appears:

```
var results = repo.Commits.QueryBy(playlistName + ".txt").ToList();
Commit result = null;
foreach (LogEntry log in results)
{
if (verbose) resultString.Add(log.Commit.Author.When.ToString("dd/MM/yy:hh:mm"));
if (log.Commit.Author.When.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yy: hh:mm") == time.ToString("dd/MM/yy: hh:mm") || log.Commit.Author.When.Date.ToString("d") == time.ToString("d")) //search only for queried day
{
    result = log.Commit;
}
```

Trying to get the diff of a single file:

```
 Patch diff = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(result.Tree, repo.Head.Tip.Tree);
 if (diff.Count() == 0) resultString.Add("No differences found!");
 string rawText = diff.Content;
 resultString.Add(String.Format("Changes in playlist: 0}",playlistName));
 foreach (string line in rawText.Split('\n')) resultString.Add(line);
```

Comment: `libgit2` is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods, so it should be possible to run a git command like the one you want, have you tried something with code? And did you get any errors?

Comment: Have a look: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-diff-%7Bfilename%7D---local.patch

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi thanks I will check taht link out